# mysql change password in session

Tags: php, mysql

I changed my password from old hash to a new hash using the following query

```
SET SESSION old_passwords=FALSE;
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('[your password]');
```

I found this query on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892607/mysql-password-hashing-method-old-vs-new. I replaced [your password] to my own password.

Now I can't log into my db again using the password I set. I was wondering is this password change forever or is the session going to expire and how long till it does.

Comment: Did you run FLUSH PRIVILEGES; query to apply privilege changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to MySQL Documentation on SET PASSWORD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-password.html)

> The SET PASSWORD statement assigns a password to an existing MySQL
> user account.   If the password is specified using the PASSWORD() or
> OLD_PASSWORD() function, the literal text of the password should be
> given. If the password is specified without using either function, the
> password should be the already-encrypted password value as returned by
> PASSWORD().
>
> With no FOR clause, this statement sets the password for the current
> user. Any client that has connected to the server using a nonanonymous
> account can change the password for that account

However, you just been struck by lightning because the same webpage says

> Important
>
> SET PASSWORD may be recorded in server logs or in a history file such as ~/.mysql_history, which means that plaintext passwords may be
> read by anyone having read access to that information. See Section
> 6.1.2, “Password Security in MySQL”.
>
> Note
>
> If you are connecting to a MySQL 4.1 or later server using a pre-4.1 client program, do not use the preceding SET PASSWORD or
> UPDATE statement without reading Section 6.1.2.3, “Password Hashing in
> MySQL”, first. The password format changed in MySQL 4.1, and under
> certain circumstances it is possible that if you change your password,
> you might not be able to connect to the server afterward.

Your password change is forever, so to speak.

### **HOW TO FIX IT**

Suppose your user is myuser@localhost, you can have someone with ALL PRIVILEGES run this

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=OLD_PASSWORD('[your password]')
WHERE user='myuser' AND host='localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If you have no DBA but can restart mysql, then do this

```
service mysql restart --skip-networking --skip-grant-tables
mysql -e"UPDATE mysql.user SET password=OLD_PASSWORD('[your password]') WHERE user='myuser' AND host='localhost'"
service mysql restart
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Going to ask my system administrator to reset my password